# Emacs on Windows 8: write-error, bad file descriptor

Tags: windows, emacs, ioerror

I just installed Emacs on Win8. However, sometimes, when I save buffer to the file, emacs will just say:

```
Write error: bad file descriptor, c:/Users/...
```

I tried different version of emacs, no help. If I restart the computer, the problem will be solved for a short time. Then is occurs again.

Any ideas ?

#### update

I run the command `toggle-debug-on-error`, it gives me the following information:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Write error" "bad file descriptor" "c:/cygwin64/home/t-xins/workspace/codesnippet/html/main.js")
write-region(nil nil "c:/cygwin64/home/t-xins/workspace/codesnippet/html/main.js" nil t "c:/cygwin64/home/t-xins/workspace/codesnippet/html/main.js")
basic-save-buffer-2()
basic-save-buffer-1()
basic-save-buffer()
save-buffer(1)
call-interactively(save-buffer nil nil)
command-execute(save-buffer)
```

I observed that when my computer get awake after sleeping, the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

Things you might try to give us more information to help with this:

Run the function `toggle-debug-on-error` so that you can get a stack trace of the error next time it happens, which might give a clue as to what is happening.

It is *possible*, but I'm not very sure of it, that it could be an encoding issue, in which case the following lines might fix it:

```el
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
(set-language-environment 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for one case of this error.
In my case, after saving once, a buffer could not be saved again,
throwing the error message mentioned above.
Saving to a different name and renaming this file did it.
Not nice - but working. So, maybe someone finds this useful:
:

```
(defun save-force (&optional override-local-key)
    "force saving a file (ignores bad-file-descriptor)"
    (interactive "P")
    (when override-local-key
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-x C-s") 'save-force)
        (print "C-x C-s overridden with 'save-force") )
    (let* ((buf-fname (buffer-file-name))
           (buf-fname1 (format "%s-temp%06d" buf-fname (random 1000000))) )
        (ignore-errors
            (write-region nil nil buf-fname1))
        (when (file-exists-p buf-fname1)
            (when (file-exists-p buf-fname)
                (delete-file buf-fname))
            (rename-file buf-fname1 buf-fname)
            (set-buffer-modified-p nil)
            (revert-buffer nil t) )))
```